# function parameters not sent correctly

Tags: javascript, function, parameters, arguments

I have the folowing functions :

```js
function showPoster(element,list_nr) 
{ 
    var image ="url('../Login/" + movie_image[list_nr] + "'), auto";
    element.style.cursor = image;
}

function putNewContent(page)
{
    for(var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
    { 
        document.getElementById("p"+i+1).onmouseover = function() { showPoster(this,(page-1)*10+i); }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when,for example,i run **putNewContent(1)** , it will call the function **showPoster()** 10 times, but the argument which arrives to **showPoster()** is always 11 (i<=10),so it finishes the for first,i gets to 11,and then it calls the function.
  How can i send the parameter i correctly ?(the list_nr argument to be the same as the i in the for as it gets evaluated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your index (`i`) is declared outside the function and not private to each instance. All functions ends up using the last one, 10 in your case.

This can be solved with `.bind()`

```
function putNewContent(page) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("p" + i + 1).onmouseover = function(i) {
      showPoster(this, (page - 1) * 10 + i);
    }.bind(null,i)
  }
}
```

Or closures

```
function putNewContent(page) {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    document.getElementById("p" + i + 1).onmouseover = (function(i) {
        return function() {
          showPoster(this, (page - 1) * 10 + i);
        }
      }
    })(i);
}
```

Both will keep a private instance of `i` for each function.

Comment: I used the version with .bind() and it works perfectly.Thanks !